# Validation Rule Profile Exemption

Tags: validation-rule, update

I have a validation Rule that I require assistance with , this validation rule should only allow fields to be updated by the two profile ids specified:

```
NOT(
    OR(
        $Profile.Id = "00e58000000yYlm",
        $Profile.Id = "00e58000000E6lK",
        AND(
            ISPICKVAL((WorkOrder.Status ), 'WithTechnician'),
            OR(
                ISCHANGED ( ProposedWorkPerformed__c),
                ISCHANGED ( ProposedOriginOfError__c ),
                ISCHANGED ( ProposedErrorComment__c ),
                ISCHANGED ( EstimatedDurationInMinutes__c ),
                ISCHANGED ( ActualWorkPerformed__c ),
                ISCHANGED ( ActualDurationInMinutes__c ),
                ISCHANGED ( ActualOriginOfError__c ),
                ISCHANGED ( ActualErrorComment__c ),
                ISCHANGED ( Status ),
                ISCHANGED ( Type__c ),
                ISCHANGED ( Source__c)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The big thing to keep in mind with validation rules is that their purpose isn't really to tell you what data is valid, but rather to tell you what data is *invalid*. It's a small shift in how you mentally frame the problem, but one that I find very helpful.

Instead of stating the outcome as "these profiles should be allowed to edit these fields", try working from "everyone who doesn't have one of these two profiles should be prevented from editing these fields".

Re-stating that a bit closer to a Validation Rule, "If the profile isn't one of our targets, and workorder status is `<X>`, and at least one of these fields are changing, then prevent the change"

**Note that** these comments are for clarity, and not in the appropriate format for a validation rule.

```
// segment 1
// User is not one of our target profiles
// The NOT() here should be limited to just the profile check
NOT(
    OR(
        Profile = profile1,
        Profile = profile2
    )
)
```

```
// segment 2
// workorder status check
ISPICKVAL((WorkOrder.Status ), 'WithTechnician')
```

```
// segment 3
// field change check
// a change to any of these fields should make this segment evaluate to "true", so OR()
//   is appropriate
OR(
    ISCHANGED(ProposedWorkPerformed__c),
    ISCHANGED(ProposedOriginOfError__c),
    ISCHANGED(ProposedErrorComment__c),
    ISCHANGED(EstimatedDurationInMinutes__c),
    ISCHANGED(ActualWorkPerformed__c),
    ISCHANGED(ActualDurationInMinutes__c),
    ISCHANGED(ActualOriginOfError__c),
    ISCHANGED(ActualErrorComment__c),
    ISCHANGED(Status),
    ISCHANGED( Type__c),
    ISCHANGED(Source__c)
)
```

The "plain language" description of what you're aiming to do tells you how these segments should be tied together (they should be `AND`-ed).

`<segment1> && <segment2> && <segment3>` would work, but the more typical approach is to use `AND()`.

```
AND(
    <segment1>,
    <segment2>,
    <segment3>
)
```

Comment: Comments are actually allowed for workflow formulas, validation rules and formula fields using the format `/* comments */`

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with OR operator on profile, AND operator on the status field, and NOT function. You haven't used/close them at appropriate places.

Below is the updated snippet.

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL(Status, "WithTechnician"),
NOT(OR(
$Profile.Id = "00e58000000yYlm",
$Profile.Id = "00e58000000E6lK")),
OR(
ISCHANGED(ProposedWorkPerformed__c),
ISCHANGED(ProposedOriginOfError__c),
ISCHANGED(ProposedErrorComment__c),
ISCHANGED(EstimatedDurationInMinutes__c),
ISCHANGED(ActualWorkPerformed__c),
ISCHANGED(ActualDurationInMinutes__c),
ISCHANGED(ActualOriginOfError__c),
ISCHANGED(ActualErrorComment__c),
ISCHANGED(Status),
ISCHANGED(Type__c),
ISCHANGED(Source__c)))
```

Take a look at sample validation rule examples [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_useful_field_validation_formulas.htm&type=0).

Thanks

Comment: The explanation is as important as the solution itself. It may be obvious to you what the difference between this and what OP currently has is, but other people may not have the requisite knowledge. Understanding the problem so it can be avoided in the future is better than blindly copy/pasting code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the snippet. However, all profiles can still update the fields with this one, just like my code above.

Comment: Can you pls re-check the criteria and also use one condition of ISCHANGED and later you can add the remaining ones? Have checked in my org and it works.  @DerekF Sure will add more details.

Comment: Understood. ISPICKVAL(Status, "WithTechnician"), was actually supposed to be ISPICKVAL(CustomObject.Status, "WithTechnician"),

Comment: Was checking 'WorkOrder' since there was no custom object mentioned.  Do you still see any other issues?

Comment: It works now, thanks

Comment: Good to know that...cheers!